# Pass argument from router to view in backbone js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm having some problems getting value that passed from backbone router to the view render function.

I have a function in my router :

```
routes: {
   "content/:contentTypeTitleID/:contentTypeID/:pageLink" : "contentAction",
}

app_router.on('route:contentAction', function(contentTypeTitleID, contentTypeID, pageLink){
    if(window.currentSection){
        window.currentSection.remove();
    }
    window.currentSection = new ContainerContent({titleID :contentTypeTitleID, typeID : contentTypeID, pl : pageLink});

    $("#webbodycontainer").html(window.currentSection.$el);
    window.currentSection.render();
});
```

The View :

```
initialize : function(options){
   console.log(this.options.typeID);
   console.log(this.options.titleID);
   console.log(this.options.pl);
},
render : function(){
   console.log(this.options.typeID);
   console.log(this.options.titleID);
   console.log(this.options.pl);
}
```

URL be like : #content/7901c296-071d-e411-90ef-0050568726db/ed05829f-071d-e401-93ef-0050568726db/1

`console.log()` in `initialize` method are alright, but I got an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeID' of undefined` in `render()`

Any idea what could be causing this. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Here is the full code in `render` method of the view :

```
render : function(){
  var _contenttem = _.template(Content);
  this.$el.append(_contenttem);

  var _content = new Content();
  var pageLink = this.options.pl;

  if(pageLink != 1){
    $("#contentDiv").html("write anything");
  }else{
    $("#contentDiv").html(_content.getContent(this.options.typeID));
  }
  $(".navigator").html(_content.writeContentType(this.options.titleID));

  $(".contentType").click(function(event){
    $('.navigator li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    if(pageLink != 1){
        $("#contentDiv").html("write anything");
    }else{
        console.log(this.options.typeID);
        console.log(this.options.titleID);
        console.log(this.options.pl);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you using Backbone version 1.1.2?

Comment: @Josh : I'm using 1.0.0

Comment: Ok, that's important, because as of Backbone 1.1.0+ they did away with the `this.options` in the constructor (http://backbonejs.org/#changelog).

Comment: @Josh : So, do I have to upgrade backbone's version?

Comment: Unless there is a good reason not to, then I'd say upgrade it. But it looks like you're not using the view correctly. I'll post my thoughts in a few minutes.

Comment: This error makes no sense with only the code we can see above

Comment: @DominicTobias : kindly have a look in my update block please.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not attaching it to the dom in the intended way. Here is my example that is showing `this.options` from within the render method working based on the code you've shown.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/mcfarljw/zwesbhbp/

Rather than using:

```
$("#webbodycontainer").html(window.currentSection.$el);
```

You should probably use:

```
currentSection.setElement("#webbodycontainer").render();
```

Comment: hmm using that, my view doesn't render properly, the el container is not shown and moreover it's still giving the same error.

Comment: well then something else is missing that isn't visible from your question. if you can recreate it using a fiddle or something else that might help.